# r ggplot 2 - set different fill colors for different facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `ggplot2` in `R`, I want to set the fill parameter to be different for each facet.  Here is some simplified code ([Also available at on my GitHub](https://github.com/TimothyChenAllen/ggplot_facets))

```
# 1. Load libraries
require(ggplot2)

# 2. Make up fake data
yr <- c(2013,2014,2015,2013,2014,2015)
widgets.made <- c(10,20,40,15,30,60)
factory <- c(rep(" Factory A",3),rep("Factory B",3))
df <- data.frame(factory, widgets.made, yr)

# 3. Create a plot with two facets
png("./factories.png")
# Note the geom_bar "fill" parameter-- I want this
# to be different for each facet; 
# Red for Factory A
# Blue for Factory B
ggplot(df) + 
        aes(yr, widgets.made) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="green") +
        facet_grid(. ~ factory)
dev.off()
```

The image produced looks like this (but I want two colors, not just one!):

[image: Factory A vs Factory B]

By the way, this is not homework; I noticed this while I was working on a Data Science assignment, but I did not need it to complete the assignment.  I just think it would be great to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
ggplot(df, aes(yr, widgets.made, fill=factory)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(. ~ factory)
```

Results

[image]

Comment: Excellent, this was what I sought.  Also, the command you gave me led me to the help for `scale_fill_*` commands, like  `scale_fill_discrete(h = c(1,40))`